# How to draw a ground as in Hill Climb Racing in Libgdx

Tags: math, libgdx, rendering, game-engine

in my project i have as the physical ground multiple box2D polylines.

Now my task is to render the ground;

I would like to use a Texture which is only opaque at the position of the ground. I want the shape of the ground to consist out of curves and not being angular shaped. Also the performance shouldn't suffer because of rendering the ground.
Basically the ground should look like the ground in Hill Climb Racing (except they're using multiple ground textures). 
[image].

I am working in Libgdx and i do really appreciate any help or ideas.

If anything isn't clear to you please ask!!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you find how to do it ?